# Convert target .NET Framework doesn't change referenced components

Tags: vb.net, project

I have an old project, I converted to Visual Studio 2010.  Of course, it remained targeting the .NET Framework 2.0.  So, when I edit the target framework in the Compile tab, and change it to 3.5, it closes and reopens the project.  However, the References still show that System, System.Data, etc. are still .NET 2.0.  Further, I cannot access the .ToList method for an array that I need, so it must not be loading the newer framework.  Does anyone have ideas on how it can work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it did minimum changes required to switch framework version, so that your breaks are minimal. If you want, you can manually remove and re-add .NET DLLs targeting a newer version. Even though in most cases upgrading version for all referenced DLLs is not a problem, in the most generic case, there may be issues (especially if you hacking deeper into .NET core).

Regarding [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261(v=vs.90).aspx), you just need to import **System.Linq**, which is in **System.Core.dll**.